# AutoResetEvent being prematurely signalled while running unit test in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c#, multithreading, unit-testing, vs-unit-testing-framework, autoresetevent

I am running a MS unit test in VS2010 to test my multi-threaded application.

The application uses an `AutoResetEvent` to synchronise threads, which is declared like so:

```
private readonly AutoResetEvent captureParsedEvent = new AutoResetEvent(false);
```

---

#### Main test thread (ID: 13)

The main test thread launches a thread to parse a capture file, and then calls `WaitOne()` on a `AutoResetEvent`, blocking until the capture is complete:

```
int id = Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId;
CaptureManager.Instance.StartProcessingPackets();
Trace.WriteLine("[" + id + "]: WAITING ON CaptureParsedEvent");
captureParsedEvent.WaitOne();
Trace.WriteLine("[" + id + "]: WAITING ON CaptureParsedEvent DONE!");

// Analyse parsed capture...
```

<sub>(**Side note:** the code originally had a call to `captureParsedEvent.Reset()` after `WaitOne()` but I removed this while investigating this problem, as my research has concluded that this may not be necessary for `AutoResetEvent` objects.)</sub>

#### Parsing thread (ID: 18)

Meanwhile, the thread which is doing the parsing signals the `AutoResetEvent` like this:

```
private void InstanceManagerStateChanged(ManagerStateEventArgs ea, object sender)
{
    int id = Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId;
    switch(ea.CurrentState)
    {
        case ManagerState.ReadPacketsDone:
            Trace.WriteLine("\t[" + id + "]: CaptureParsedEvent SIGNAL");
            captureParsedEvent.Set();
            Trace.WriteLine("\t[" + id + "]: CaptureParsedEvent DONE!");
            break;
    }
}
```

---

Normally, everything behaves well and I see the following expected output in the output window:

```
[13]: WAITING ON CaptureParsedEvent
    [18]: CaptureParsedEvent SIGNAL
    [18]: CaptureParsedEvent DONE!
[13]: WAITING ON CaptureParsedEvent DONE!
```

However, I am seeing the following output intermittently:

```
[13]: WAITING ON CaptureParsedEvent
[13]: WAITING ON CaptureParsedEvent DONE!
```

This is obviously causing me issues because the capture hasn't really finishing parsing.

The above place is the only occurrence of `captureParsedEvent.Set();` so I know that nobody else is signalling the event.

A few questions:

1. Is `Trace.WriteLine()` thread-safe and outputting the traces in the correct order?
2. I have only seen this issue when running unit tests in VS2010 -- is there something funny going on with tests being run in parallel, and usage of threads in this scenario that may be causing issues?  My understanding is that the tests run in serial, but not sure if this is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved my issue.

It turns out that for each packet that the code was processing, it was adding the `InstanceManagerStateChanged()` callback to the list of delegates:

```
CaptureManager.Instance.ManagerStateChanged += InstanceManagerStateChanged;
```

but we weren't correctly unsubscribing, which meant that I may have been getting notifications from the previous packet.

Unsubscribing prior to processing the next packet fixed this issue:

```
CaptureManager.Instance.ManagerStateChanged -= InstanceManagerStateChanged;
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that what you're getting is caused by the fact that at the time of evaluation, `ea.CurrentState` is not `ManagerState.ReadPacketsDone`, so it's skipping the code inside that case statement. `ManualResetEvent`s don't set themselves and if they did, then it would be a HUGE problem for everybody (I've never heard of somebody else having such a problem), so you just have to make sure that nobody else is setting the event.

To question 1: `Trace.WriteLine()` is thread safe, but if you have multiple threads making calls to writeline you are not guaranteed that those calls will get executed in order. However, in your case the `SIGNAL` and `DONE` messages will be written one after the other since they're executed in the same thread. More importantly, if you get the correct state, then at least `CaptureParsedEvent SIGNAL` will be printed before `WAITING ON CaptureParsedEvent DONE` because it happens before you set the manual reset event. After you signal, you're not guaranteed the order of prints for the `WAITING ON CaptureParsedEvent DONE` and `CaptureParsedEvent DONE`.

If another thread is writing at the same time, then it can write something in between them. But as I already said: it's most likely caused by `ea.CurrentState` not being `ManagerState.ReadPacketsDone`.

To question 2: when you're dealing with concurrency, there is always "something funny" going on or it's as "funny" as what you normally get with concurrent programming: you just have to *thread carefully*. Again, I don't think your issue is coming from concurrency, it just simply looks like you're not handling the correct case and/or somebody else has access to the same `ManualResetEvent`.

Comment: The only place the `Set()` is called is within that `ReadPacketsDone` case, which is why this is baffling me.  If I'm not seeing that trace, the `Set()` isn't being called, so I don't understand how the `WaitOnce()` is unblocking.

Comment: @LeopardSkinPillBoxHat I can only take your word for it, but it still contradicts the basic operation of `ManualResetEvent` and the likelihood that `ManualResetEvent` is broken is **very small** (to say the least). So I'm throwing the ball back at your court.

Comment: For the record, I am using `AutoResetEvent`, not `ManualResetEvent`.

Comment: @LeopardSkinPillBoxHat sorry that I keep saying `ManualResetEvent`, but the only difference between the two is that the `AutoResetEvent` automatically goes to **non-signaled** state whereas the `ManualResetEvent` has to be manually reset to non-signaled. None of them will signal unless the `Set()` method is called... if you can create a small test that reproduces the exact problem then I think we can be more helpful, but without seeing the code my only assumption can be that something is calling the `Set()` method.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I have confirmed that there is only a single place my event is being `Set()` from -- in the code I posted.  I suspect something is happening here which is unique to how this code runs in a test environment, similar to what @bryanbcook has suggested.

Comment: Thanks for your help - I resolved the issue now.  Please see my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10167972/22489.

Answer (score 1):

By default Visual Stufio 2010 does not run tests in parallel, you must enable this by manually editing the test settings file (parallelExecutionCount=0).

In looking at the code you've provided, the culprit may be related to the fact that the signaling is done within a singleton (CaptureManager.Instance). There may be situations where previous tests have already executed and the ManagerState has already completed. Try running the test by itself to validate this assumption.

If you're running the tests sequentially you may need to reset the state of the singleton between tests to avoid side-effects like this. Note, however, this must be done everywhere the singleton is used, which may prove to be less than ideal if this class is used heavily throughout the code-base.

If you're running the tests in parallel, all bets are off because you cannot guarantee a well known state at the time the test executes. Your best option is to redesign the relationships between objects so that the graph can be instantiated and executed without side effects.

Comment: Thanks, this seems like something worth investigating, as it seems to be interference between tests (when I run the tests separately, this problem doesn't seem to happen).  But can you explain how this would occur?  Doesn't each test start in a new process, and thus `CaptureManager.Instance` would be destroyed and re-created for each test?

Comment: MSTest uses a single AppDomain for all tests so Singletons will contain shared state between tests. On the other hand, test classes are instantiated per test so their instance variables are reset between test executions, but managing the state of complex objects (unmanaged COM components, singletons, databases, file system, IDisposable, etc) is up to you to reset to a well known state between tests. You can use the [ClassInitialize] and [ClassCleanup] attributes to reset state but keep in mind that test-execution may be non-deterministic and won't necessarily run in a fixed order.

Comment: Thanks for your help - I resolved the issue now.  Please see my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10167972/22489.